# Using a struct member as a member in another struct

Tags: go, struct, embedding

```
type (
    A struct {
        a string
    }

    B struct {
        b *A.a
    }
)
```

I get this error:

```
A.a undefined (type A has no method a)
```

Am I missing something here? Or is it not allowed in Go?

Answer (score 4):

When you define a struct field, you have to specify [its name and its type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) like you did with struct `A.a`. But in struct `B`:

```
b *A.a
```

`*A.a` is not a type.

You can't embed a field of a `struct` in another struct. Note that however you can embed *complete* structs in another by omitting the *name* part like this:

```
type (
    A struct {
        a string
    }

    B struct {
        A
    }
)
```

The result is that all the fields and methods of type `A` will also be member of struct `B`. If you need the embedded struct `A` of `B`, you can access it by referring to it as the type name:

```
var b B
fmt.Println(b.A)
```

Another thing you can do is have a field in `B` which is a pointer and it points to the field of an *existing value* of type `A`:

```
B struct {
    ap *string
}

a := A{a:"test"}
b := B{ap:&a.a} // B.ap will point to a.a

fmt.Println(*b.ap) // Prints "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `*A.a` as the type specifier for field `b`. The only thing you're missing is that you should have `b string` or `b *string` there (if you want a string field in struct B at least).

Now if your goal is to do something more like 'inheriting' the field then you should *embed* `A` in `B` which will give `B` a property called `a`. That would look like this;

```
type B struct {
      A
}
```

This is the most similar construct to inheritance Go offers. If you were to embed here you would be able to do something like;

```
var instanceOfB = &B{}
fmt.Println(instanceOfB.a)
```

Which is functionally equivalent of having B inherit from A (in this case, the two things are not the same though and behavior is different in many. I just think it's helpful to compare/contrast to inheritance). At this point you can access an property or method on `A` directly from an instance of `B`. It's best to avoid name collisions though they won't cause a compiler error. If you do have naming collisions between embedded types or the embeddor and an embedded type the decision of which method/property to use is made at runtime and I'm not sure what the resolution rules are but I think you can find them in the language spec.

Now my last idea... If your goal is to reference the `a` property in an instance of `A` from some instance of `B`, you just want to include a sting pointer in `B` and set it to `&A.a` in your constructor a static initializer when you instantiate `B`. However this is probably a bad practice as it defies the concept of encapsulation and is just very obviously error prone.